# Where is the proper place to implement "LOGOUT" function in PasswordChangeView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

Hello Stackoverflow community.

Where is the best place to implement LOGOUT function in PasswordChangeView

I tried

```py
class PasswordCorrectionView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = "admin/password_change.html”
    form_class = PwdChgForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)   # here
        return PasswordChangeView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

but it rises:

```
NotImplementedError at /account/password/change
Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser.
```

That's reasonable cos I cant save  AnonymousUser password anyway.

So question is what method is the best one to override here in PasswordChangeView???

Or second option override  some method  in the forms:

```py
class PwdChgForm(PasswordChangeForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.user.is_activated = False
        user_registrated.send(PwdChgForm, instance=self.user) # signal to the email sender
        PasswordChangeForm.save(self, commit=True)
```

I need user to logout after he has chaged his password (then confirm it via email, etc) All this work except LOGOUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)   # here
        return PasswordChangeView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

to

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    PasswordChangeView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    logout(request)   # here
    return redirect('your-login-url')
```

Comment: @ Shafikur Rahman.Thanks, it does work.  Only  HttpResponseRedirect needed instead of redirect